# Must be root to push/commit to mercurial repositories

Tags: mercurial, sudo

I am using Ubuntu on my workstation and whenever I try to commit/push to a Mercurial repository located on a CIFS share in my LAN, I get this error  thrown: `abort: Operation not permitted: /media/repos/myRepo/.hg/journal.dirstate`

However, prepending any command that causes this with `sudo`, will let mercurial continue without throwing any errors at me.

What should I do stop having to `sudo` every commit?

Comment: Fix the permissions on your repository (perhaps both the master one and your local one).

Comment: Done that. Chmod:ed both already to 777 and no change.

Comment: It would also help to diagnose the problem if you show the result of `ls -la` in the `.hg` directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your user doesn’t have write permissions for `/media/repos/myRepo`. You can check the owner and permissions using `ls -la`. Depending on the result of that you should either:

Try changing the permissions with `chmod` to allow access by your user or group.

```
sudo chmod -R ug+w /media/repos/myRepo
```

(`ug+w` means add write permissions for the group and the owner user, this will work if you’re in the same group as the owner. Otherwise, you could try just `+w` which will add it for all users, but this is less secure.)

Try changing the owner with `chown` to your user or group.

```
sudo chown -R <myuser>:<mygroup> /media/repos/myRepo
```

(Both `myuser` and `mygroup` are optional)

Also be sure to use `chown` and `chmod` recursively on the entire repository. If `journal.dirstate` is recreated every time (which I think is what happens), it inherits its permissions from the `.hg` directory, so any permissions you change on the file itself may get lost.

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be related to a [bug](http://selenic.com/pipermail/mercurial-devel/2012-March/038574.html) in Mercurial versions prior to 2.1.2 related to a failed transaction.

The problem begins to crop up if a `hg push` fails midway through the operation. This might occur, for example, due to the network dropping out or a hook on the server-side aborting a transaction. This can lead to a stale file `journal.dirstate` being left inside the server-side `.hg` directory.

From this point on, no user other than the owner of `journal.dirstate` or root will be able to push, regardless of the file permissions on `journal.dirstate`. This is because during a push, Mercurial attempts to `chmod` the file to the user performing the push, giving the error you observed: `Operation not permitted`.

To solve the problem, you can try either of the following:

- Have the owner of the file `journal.dirstate` perform a successful push. The stale file should be cleaned up in the process; or
- Update the server version of Mercurial to version 2.1.2 or above; or
- Delete the file `journal.dirstate` on the server-side.

After carrying out any of these, all users should be able to push once more.